# Add Lightning Web Component to Lightning Tab

Tags: tab, lightning-web-components

I am trying to figure out how to add a Lightning Web Component to a Lightning tab.  I have it on the Home Page, but I would like it to be on its own tab.  I feel like there should be an option to expose it to the Lightning tabs.  When I am in the Tabs section, I don't see my LWC listed.

Comment: You can if you have a Lighting Page Tab created.

Comment: @JayantDas how about lightning component tab?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal as long as your LWC is wrapped within an Aura component, then Yes. Because you cannot really edit a Lighting (Aura) Component tab but only associate it with an aura component.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From Winter 20 release you are able to set it as Tab. All you need to do is:

1. Open `-meta.xml` file from your LWC component
2. Change is exposed to True: `<isExposed>true</isExposed>`
3. Add `<target>lightning__Tab</target>`
4. Open Tab from setup and under **Lightning Component Tabs** press New and select your LWC component.

Your file at the end should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

As stated in comments, `My Domain` is a prerequisite to `Lightning Component Tabs`

Comment: fyi, My Domain is a prerequisite to Lightning Component Tabs

Answer (score 6):

With Winter 20 release, we can create the Lightning Tab using LWC component. You will just have to add the below tag in the `-meta.xml` file of LWC component.

```
<target>lightning__Tab</target>
```

Comment: Although this will be good *IF* Salesforce does release this and their safe harbour statements mean you cannot rely on this info.

Comment: It's available in Summer'20 Pre-Release Org. You can cross-verify there.

Comment: Your answer is only partially correct. The full solution is on this link : https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/08/lightning-web-components-as-custom-tab.html

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this by:

- Setup
- Lightning App Builder
- List item
- Create a new App Page
- Add the LWC to the page
- Associate the page with an App

Comment: Funny, this isn't the correct answer to your own question.

Comment: @compski  I don't understand your comment.  The solution I listed was a way to accomplish what I needed.  I put the LWC on a page, added the page to an app, and then assigned the app to a tab.

Comment: Why do you need to put LWC on a page to then assign it to a tab? Your question after all was "When I am in the Tabs section, I don't see my LWC listed." This article shows you how to have it on Tab section and have ur LWC listed https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/08/lightning-web-components-as-custom-tab.html

Answer (score 1):

So far (Spring '19), using a Lightning web component inside a tab isn't supported, as listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/get_started_supported_experiences).

What you can do is [wrap it inside an aura component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition), and create a tab for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, after tried various solutions, I noticed in Setup -> Tabs is a link for help: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_tabdef.htm&type=5, there say for see Lightning Component Tabs you need a deployed my domain:

> NOTE To expose Lightning components via Lightning component tabs, you
>   must enable and deploy My Domain.

I deployed My Domain in Setup-> My Domain and then in tabs appears the option Lightning Component Tabs