# Regarding Lightning Web Component Tab

Tags: lightning-web-components, visualforce-component, tab, home-page-component, admin

I have tried to create a LWC tab in tabs menu.but i could not able to select my component from the list.i have 3+ Components and even i've created my-domain too,still i'm facing the issue.....can anyone help me how to resolve this....thanks in advance:)
[image: I can't choose my component here]

Comment: did you set the target as tab in XMl

Comment: yes bro <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>

Comment: You need to set <target>lightning__Tab</target>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Lightning Web Component to Lightning Tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253890/add-lightning-web-component-to-lightning-tab)