# Any way to avoid the blue screen background showing on a custom LWC lightning__Tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components, list-view, custom-metadata

I am creating a custom LWC component that presents a list of Custom Metadata records using the same sort of styling that a default list of SObject Records would use. The mechanism works as described in e.g. [Add Lightning Web Component to Lightning Tab](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253890/add-lightning-web-component-to-lightning-tab).

But I get blue screen background not added by my LWC:

[image: blue borders]

whereas the default list does not have that:

[image: no borders]

Any way to eliminate that blue background for a custom LWC lightning__Tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue part is always present on a Lightning Tab's background. You can "fix" this with a bit of a negative margin.

## Aura

```
.THIS {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: -1em;
}
```

## LWC

```
:host() {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: -1em;
}
```

You may need to experiment with the exact margin you need, and you might need some additional selectors, but it's certainly possible to hide the entire background with a bit of patience.